# C++11: When do we need to specialize "=default" for default member function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, default, member

Did a simple test and found that, "=default" only works for special member functions, like this:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<utility>
struct Base{
    Base(int){printf("Base(int)\n");}
};
struct Derived{
    Derived(int)=default;
};
int main(){
    Derived d(0);
    return 0;
}
```

clang will report compilation error:

```
error: only special member functions may be defaulted
```

So if only "special member function" is allowed, this "=default" seems to be useless: because if I don't give definition of special member functions in "Derived", compiler will generate one for me, equal to using "=default".

So my question is, why and when do we need "=default"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> because if I don't give definition of special member functions in "Derived", compiler will generate one for me, equal to using "=default".

Because there're cases that some of the special member functions won't be generated, e.g. when you declare copy constructor, move constructor won't be generated, then move requests would be processed by copy constructor. Adding (defaulted) move constructor could prevent that:

```
struct Derived {
    Derived(const Derived&) { ... }
    Derived(Derived&&) = default;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

> if I don't give definition of special member functions in "Derived", compiler will generate one for me, equal to using "=default".

No, actually.

Declare any constructor - and your compiler-provided default constructor will disappear. To bring it back (in its compiler-provided form), you can define it as `= default`.

Provide a user-declared destructor - and your compiler-provided move constructor and move assignment operator will disappear. To bring them back, you can define them as `= default`.

Provide a user-declared move assignment operator - and your compiler-provided copy constructor and copy assignment operator will disappear. Well, you get the idea.

`= default` is used when you need to bring back compiler-provided functionality of special member function in situations, when other circumstances caused that function to "disappear".